# Getting nearby localities

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, google-places-api

I have tried a lot and googled a lot but finally I'm ending up by putting this query here.

I have user's long and lat, now I want to get all the nearby localities of specific range i.e 500 Kilometres. I searched and came to know google places API can help me out in this, but It is not bringing correct result.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.7167,73.0667&radius=500&type=funeral_home&sensor=false&key=key
```

In above mentioned link I have given a type "funeral_home" respectively but the result it brings is not of type funeral_home. It is bringing data from every type irrespective of the type i provide. Anyone please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters name is `types` (not `type`). Changing that returns zero results (no errors).

The `radius` parameter is actually measured in meters (not `km`), with a max of 50,000. Changing that too gives 5 results (no errors).

Comment: I have tried geocoding and autocomplete. Will search more thanks anyways